# Order text file by frequency of occrrences

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Given a text file which will have duplicate lines in it such as:

```
this is a line
this is a line
this is another line
this is a line
this is yet another line
this is yet another line
```

Is it possible on the command line to print out each unique line but ordered by the frequency of which it appears.

I.e. the result of the previous text would be:

```
this is a line
this is yet another line
this is another line
```

The they appear 3, 2 and 1 times respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

`sort file|uniq -c|sort -rn`

EDIT:
Also if you want to delete the counter at the beginning of the lines just pipe
`sed 's/^\s*[0-9]* \(.*\)$/\1/'`
at the end of the above command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
awk '{ a[$0]++ } END {for (i in a) print a[i], i }' | sort -nr
3 this is a line
2 this is yet another line
1 this is another line
```